# Unable to attach igraph or highcharter in Rstudio (libglpk.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

Tags: r, igraph, r-highcharter

I have a [binder](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/nhsbsa-data-analytics/coffee-and-coding/HEAD?urlpath=lab) set up that makes use of highcharter. The package is installed, the system can find it and it is up to date. But when trying to attach it with library I get this:

```
> library(highcharter)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘highcharter’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/srv/rlibs/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
  libglpk.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I noted the mention of igraph, so I tried attaching that, but get the same error:

```
> library(igraph)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘igraph’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/srv/rlibs/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
  libglpk.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried installing the latest dev version from github. The result of this was an error:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘igraph’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
    unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpK0dUBK/Rinst15a72b8aab6/00LOCK-igraph/00new/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
     libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   Error: loading failed
```

The binder system info is:

```
> Sys.info()
                                                       sysname 
                                                       "Linux" 
                                                       release 
                                                    "5.4.129+" 
                                                       version 
                         "#1 SMP Wed Aug 18 19:58:18 PDT 2021" 
                                                      nodename 
"jupyter-nhsbsa-2ddata-2dana-2dffee-2dand-2dcoding-2d5y1715cc" 
                                                       machine 
                                                      "x86_64"
```

After several hours of Googling I've reached the limit of what I can do to troubleshoot this, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Resolved by adding `libglpk-dev` to the `apt.txt` file. It is strange tho, as this did not used to be needed and it worked.

Comment: Since you got it working, that's the important thing. Tracking down what changed may not be worth it. Maybe the package itself added igraph as a dependency? My other speculation would be that is you could, you'd get better and faster building by moving all your R stuff from `installs.R` into `environment.yml`. See the R-conda example [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/r-conda) but note where it says: "Note that these two approaches cannot be combined, so you cannot install R packages via Conda and via an install.R " You can though add a file you trigger to run that isn't `installs.R`.

Comment: See examples of R-conda use [here](https://github.com/fomightez/chapter7/tree/master/binder) and [here](https://github.com/fomightez/r_phylogenetics_worshop/tree/main/binder). Usually the recipes using mamba/conda make sure you don't need `apt.txt` because it installs those linux dependencies whereas other package managers sometimes cannot. MyBinder now uses mamba as a replacement for conda and it tends to be the fastest builds.